# Django MultiModelForms not saving in second model

Tags: django-models, django-forms, multi-model-forms

I have a model that has additional information I need to attach to the user's if they are part of a specific group. I have built a simple CreateView in order to test this working. Unfortunetly, it's not saving all the information in the second model. This is my first time using betterforms, and I followed the docs. However it looks like I'm missing something. Here is my current code:

**Forms.py:**

```
# Operator Creation Form
class OperatorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OperatorProfile
        fields = ('cdl', 'endorsement', 'cdl_expiration')


class UserCreationMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': UserCreationForm,
        'profile': OperatorProfileForm,
    }

    # Save the user first, because the profile needs a user before it
    # can be saved.
    def save(self, commit=True):
        objects = super(UserCreationMultiForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            user = objects['user']
            user.save()
            profile = objects['profile']
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

        return objects
```

**Views.py:**

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'


class OperatorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = OperatorProfile
    template_name = 'pages/operatorprofile_form.html'
    form_class = UserCreationMultiForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

**Models.py:**

```
class CDL(models.Model):
    cdl_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cdl_type


class Endorsement(models.Model):
    endorsement_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.endorsement_type


class OperatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cdl = models.ManyToManyField('CDL')
    endorsement = models.ManyToManyField('Endorsement')
    cdl_expiration = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Currently it's not saving the ForeignKeys in the OperatorProfile model, but the other settings are saving just fine. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well...i'm an idiot. I forgot about save_m2m(). Here is the solution for people who are wondering.

**forms.py:**

```
# Operator Creation Form
class OperatorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OperatorProfile
        fields = ('cdl', 'endorsement', 'cdl_expiration')


class UserCreationMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': UserCreationForm,
        'profile': OperatorProfileForm,
    }
```

**Views.py:**

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'


class OperatorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = OperatorProfile
    template_name = 'pages/operatorprofile_form.html'
    form_class = UserCreationMultiForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Save the user first, because the profile needs a user before it
        # can be saved.
        user = form['user'].save()
        profile = form['profile'].save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        form['profile'].save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('index'))
```